# Waiting for count in rolling time window to go down before executing request

Tags: c#, queue

Lets say I have a function that can be started at any given time, and that function sometimes has a lot of requests to do and sometimes a little, but I never want to do more than 20 requests per minute. I do however always want all requests to be executed.

```
foreach (var user in users)
{
    while (requestsInLastMinute < 20)
    {
        // Waiting for requests to get freed
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    user.ExecuteRequest();

    requestsInLastMinute++;
}
```

Is there an efficient way to do this, but where the counter only counts the requests done in the last minute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be this:

```
var requestsInLastMinute = 0;
var lastMinute = DateTime.Now.Minute;

foreach (var user in users)
{
    while (requestsInLastMinute >= 20)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Minute != lastMinute)
        {
            requestsInLastMinute = 0;
            lastMinute = DateTime.Now.Minute;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    user.ExecuteRequest();
    requestsInLastMinute++;
}
```

A solution based on MemoryCache:

```
MemoryCache cache = new MemoryCache("my memory cache");

foreach (var user in users)
{
    while (cache.Count() >= 20)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    user.ExecuteRequest();
    cache.Add(new CacheItem(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), new CacheItemPolicy() { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1) });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, good simple solution. Second solution seems to be Framework only, since it depends on `System.Runtime.Caching`.